# How can I fix a header that floats to the top of the page on certain browsers and not on others?

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-4

When I look at [www.kentkercher.com](http://kentkercher.com) in my browser, everything looks normal.

However, when I check it inside [GeoPeeker](https://geopeeker.com/fetch/?url=kentkercher.com), the H1 floats to the top of the page.

I can't find the problem in Chrome Inspect. Can someone please help me know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have this CSS added and it will solve the problem::

```
.my-auto {
position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks! fixed it. learned something new for future situations in case this comes up again.